# prepared statement where value is in array

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

In a php page, I have an array, similar to this:

```
$category = array(16, 22, 23);
```

Then I am doing a database query with a prepared statement. I would like to get all rows where the field `category` contains one of the values from that `$category` array and where `price` is lower than a value stored in the variable `$price`.

Among others I read the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28319614/5641669) question and tried to use `find_in_set()` as described there (and at a lot of other places), but somehow I can't make it work within the prepared statement. I tried this:

```
/*  database connection "$db" is established beforehand and works  */

if($ps = $db->prepare("
   SELECT id, product, category, price 
   FROM products
   WHERE price <= ? and find_in_set(?, category)
   ORDER BY id") {
     $ps->bind_param("ds", $price, $category); 
     $ps->execute();
     $ps->bind_result($id, $name, $cat, $pr);
     while($ps->fetch()) {
       /* ...  echo the results .....  */
     }
    $ps->free_result();
    $ps->close();
 }
```

But I get an empty result.

If I try to use "dd"  or "di" instead of "ds" in the `bind_param()` line, I do get results, but the wrong ones - I get all rows with category *1*.

I also tried to use `category IN ?` instead of `find_in_set(?, category)`, but that won't work either.

What can I do to make that work? Any help appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/passing-an-array-to-a-query-using-a-where-clause sound similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two issues:

- The list should be passed as *second* argument to [`find_in_set`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), so it should be:

  ```
  find_in_set(category, ?)
  ```
- That argument should be of type string (comma separated values). So first convert your array to such a string with [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

  ```
  $csv = implode(",", $category);
  ```

Code:

```
if($ps = $db->prepare("
   SELECT id, product, category, price 
   FROM products
   WHERE price <= ? and find_in_set(category, ?)
   ORDER BY id") {
     $csv = implode(",", $category);
     $ps->bind_param("ds", $price, $csv); 
     $ps->execute();
     $ps->bind_result($id, $name, $cat, $pr);
     while($ps->fetch()) {
       /* ...  echo the results .....  */
     }
    $ps->free_result();
    $ps->close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find values where $category belongs to a certain set try using IN. Just a note you cannot pass an array into a string like you have above.

Also don't forget to convert your array to a CSV string using [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$category = array(16, 22, 23);
$cat_str = implode(",",$category);  //16,22,23

$ps = $db->prepare("
   SELECT id, product, category, price 
   FROM products
   WHERE price <= ? and category IN (?)
   ORDER BY id") {
$ps->bind_param("ds", $price, $cat_str);
```

Comment: Hmm - that only returns the rows from the first value in the string. But the way @trincot describes it works for me, so I am all set. Still, thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: @Johannes I noted an error in my code above omitted the `category` before IN. I also used [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08b368/1) to display results above. It's a good tool to use to have people help you. UNsure how you only got one result. :(

Answer (score 0):

if i tried the same case , then i would probably have done it like this

```
SELECT id, product, category, price 
 FROM products
WHERE category = '16' || category = '22' || category = '23' and price < $price`
```

i am assuming   your `$category` array variable is fixed , it's not dynamically appending value .

I answered only your query part . i'd hope you have php coding convention idea rather than putting the entire statement in the `if` statement .

if still has anything to ask about , please go ahead

Comment: What is  `||`? And how would this work for any given array `$category`?

Comment: sir ,  || is equivalent to OR , and i probably i have mentioned above that i am assuming if he has  finite array value , if his array grows dynamically then he might have to  follow your way .,

Comment: True for the first point, unless the [relevant configuration](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat) has been set for it to mean string-concatenation.

Comment: well, that's basically how I did it before I had to compare more than two values. But with more values that's getting rather complicated and additionally, my array/s now have different number/s of values, so I can't use that.